# How do I change the text of a link?

Tags: views, 8

How do I change the text of a link in Views?

Under 'Fields' I have Content:Title (the default)...and that's what I want. It links to the piece of content with the link being the Title of that document. But I want to change the link text to something else.

I tried clicking that field. It opens up a dialog. Under 'Rewrite Results' I selected 'Override the output of this field with custom text' and put in my custom text. But now instead of it being a link it's just static text. That's useless.

Replacement patterns don't have any links listed just {{title}} and {{ title__value }} == Raw value

'Link to this content' is still checked at the top btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Fields add *Path* and _Exclude from display. In your title, **uncheckmark** *Link to the Content*.

In rewrite results, checkmark *Override the output of this field with custom text* and put `<a href="{{ path }}">Custom Text</a>`. Alternatively, in rewrite results, checkmark *Output this field as a custom link*, for the path put `{{ path }}` and scroll down a bit to *Title text* and write your title here.

Comment: Unfortunately "Title text" only changes the title attribute of the a tag and not the link text.